# Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'UIView'

Tags: swift

[image: Error]

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type
>   'UIView' to expected argument type 'UIView'

Comment: Never include code as a screenshot in a question. Please edit your question to include code as text with proper code formatting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Try with this:**

```
ScrollView1.addSubview(imageView)
```

Basically, You are adding the image instance in the scrollView but the required param is a type of `UIVIew` and the image wrapper is `UIImageView` so you need to add the wrapper not the image directly.